# Lazy load different layouts - angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am building an application in angular 9 and I'm still very new to all this. I want to lazy load different layouts based on the routes. All I found is that I should do something like this:

In my **app.routes.ts**

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
},
{
    path: 'settings',
    component: DifferentLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/pages/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsModule)
}
```

But by doing this am I eagerly loading all the layout components? What if I have 10 different layouts, am I loading all of them when I navigate to a single page?

Answer (score 1):

As per the routes you have mentioned in the question . You have two modules *HomeModule* and *DifferentLayoutComponent*. These two modules chunk will be downloaded when the user visited its corresponding path. Once visited the module will not be downloaded again if the visit the path again, because we already downloaded it. If you want to download other modules after the initial module is eagerly loaded , you can make use of **preloading strategy**.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself really well. What you said is valid for the settings.module and the home.module. But what of the MainLayoutComponent and DifferentLayoutComponent? If I visit the home route, is the DifferentLayoutComponent gonna be eagerly loaded?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to load the different layout as a module in the app routing module like this (`app-routing.module.ts`):

```js
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('../different-layout/different-layout.module').then(m => m.DifferentLayoutModule)
}
```

then in the DifferentLayoutModule you add the routing like this: (`different-layout-routing.module.ts`)

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: DifferentLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'foo',
            component: FooComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

then of course, the Different layout component should look something like this (`different-layout.component.html`):

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet>
   Here it will be injected your foo component
</router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```